# how to inherit /override text styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to change the style of all e.g. `h6` children in reactjs/material-ui, without theming?

I tried the following and some others:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    someClass: {
        h6: {
            fontSize: "0.5rem !important",
        },
    }
});

function functionA() {

const classes = useStyles();

return(
    <div className={classes.someClass}>
        <Typography variant="h6">foobar</Typography>
    </div>
)
}
```

P.S. I don't want to set a className for every child since this is really a big text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `& parent` selector any h6 tag under someClass fontsize will increase will be 0.5rem

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& h6": {
      fontSize: "0.5rem !important",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: If answer is helpful please aceepts the answer along with up vote, would encourage us answer here